# How To Call Parent Class Method From Another Parent Class Method

Tags: javascript

So I have the following below. How do I make it where when I call `rabbit.halfRun();` it runs the code in `Animal.run()` instead of `Rabbit.run()`

```js
class Animal {

  constructor(name) {
    this.speed = 0;
    this.name = name;
  }

  run(speed) {
    this.speed += speed;
    console.log(`${this.name} runs with speed ${this.speed}.`);
  }

  
  halfRun(){
    var newSpeed = this.speed / 2;
    // expect to be run() from Animal class, not Rabbit class
    this.run(newSpeed)
  }

}

class Rabbit extends Animal {

  
  run(speed) {
    var speed = speed * 2;
    super.run(speed);
  }


}

let rabbit = new Rabbit("White Rabbit");

rabbit.run(5); // expect and get 10
rabbit.halfRun(); // expect 5 but I get 20 because it is running the run() from Rabbit
```

Comment: just have a "private" method that is like `runImpl`

Comment: Actually both `run` methods from Parent and Child class are executed because of `super.run(speed);`. You can confirm it by adding a `console.log` statement in the `run` method from Rabbit

Comment: **Not related** to the question itself, but for `rabbit.halfRun()` I reckon you should expect `15`, not `5`. Here is the sequence (supposing you get the behaviour you want): `this.speed` set to `10`, then `newSpeed` set to `5`, and finally `this.speed` set to `10 + 5`, giving `15`.

Comment: So is it not possible to call the old run method from Animal and not the overwritten one from Rabbit? I'm starting to think it is not possible. And yes I know both are executed, that is because `Rabbit.run()` is called and it calls  `Animal.run()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its like function overriding where the actual method to be called is decided at the runtime based on the instance its pointing to.

so because the `rabbit` vairable is pointing to an object of `class Rabbit` and `class Rabbit` has overriding method `run` on it so even if you call the `halfRun` from parent class its actually calling the `run` method of `class Rabbit`. its because the actual function to be called was decided at runtime based on the object the `rabbit` vairable is pointing to.

So i think its expected result and its fine.

but yes then in Javascript i guess there is no such keyword like `self` which should call the method of current class in time of inheritance.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer. While all the other answers did a good job explaining what is happening they did not answer the question, "Is it possible to run `Animal.run()` instead of `Rabbit.run()`." While this one does not tell me how to do it, it lets me know that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting 20 is because in your `halfRun` function:

```
function halfRun(){
  var newSpeed = this.speed / 2;
  this.run(newSpeed);
}
```

You are calling `this.run(newSpeed)` which is referring to the rabbit class' run method instead of the animal one since you are calling `rabbit.halfRun()`. Therefore, it will be calling the rabbit class' implementation of `run()` since it has been overridden

Also, I believe you are setting up your halfRun() function wrong because although you halve the speed, you are still adding it onto the current speed value.

To fix your issue, you can simply just set the speed in your half run function:

```
function halfRun(){
  this.speed=this.speed / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because halfrun is calling both methods.'run' method of the rabbit class to multiply it with 2 and then 'run' of rabbit class is running super run of animal class. so both run methods are in action.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is something like

when rabbit.run() is called the speed variable holds the value of 10 and prints it

speed = 10

when rabbit.halfRun() is called it will divide the value by 2 which means 10/2 is five which should be expected output

before to the end of method you called the  this.run(newSpeed)// this.run(5)

so it will call the run method in the rabbit class

so speed = speed * 2 // 5 * 2

which is 10

at last you are calling the super.run(speed) // super.run(10)

since previously rabbit.run() has been executed the speed holds the value 10

so this.speed =+ speed // 10 =+ 10  which gives  20

Answer (score 0):

I have added logs to describe the code hope you will understand why you got 20 as the result.
This is what happens to your speed,

0 ->  5*2  ->  0+10  ->  10/2  ->  5*2  ->  10+10  -> 20

```js
class Animal {

  constructor(name) {
    this.speed = 0;
    this.name = name;
  }

  run(speed) {
    console.log(`Received ${speed} from Rabbit class`);
    console.log(`Adding ${speed} to ${this.speed}`);
    this.speed += speed;
    console.log(`Current speed at run(Animal class): ${this.speed}.`);
  }

  
  halfRun(){
    console.log(`Deviding the current speed ${this.speed} by 2`);
    var newSpeed = this.speed / 2;
    console.log(`New speed passed to Rabbit class ${newSpeed}`);
    this.run(newSpeed)
  }

}

class Rabbit extends Animal {

  
  run(speed) {
    console.log(`Current speed: ${this.speed}`);
    console.log(`Multiplying ${speed} by 2`);
    var speed = speed * 2;
    console.log(`Passing ${speed} to Animal class`);
    super.run(speed);
  }


}

let rabbit = new Rabbit("White Rabbit");

rabbit.run(5); // expect 10
rabbit.halfRun(); // expect 20
```